# How to detect an empty input field on submit and have Jquery replace it with a specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've seen various similar questions posted, but I can't quite seem to get all the pieces together.

I have a really simple form with an option single input field. I'd like to allow the user to input a value to use, but if they don't I want it to use a default, but only on submit.

Here's the HTML and JS I'm working with. This simply grabs the input value and adds it to the button URL. What I need it to do is see if it's blank on submit only and replace it with "NoName"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(e) {  
    var inputvalue = $("#rep").val();
    window.open("https://example.com/"+inputvalue, "_blank");
    });
});
</script>

<form id="options">
    <p><input type="text" id="rep" name="rep" placeholder="Your Rep ID: " style="width:auto;" value="" /></p>
    <p><button type="button" id="button" style="color:white; background-color: blueviolet; border:none; border-radius: 3px;">GO!</button></p>
</form>
```

The examples and solutions I've seen have it using placeholders, or onBlur events that cause the box to keep changing if they click in or out of it. I'd like this to stay blank, unless they enter something, then the button URL would change based on that alone.

If empty > use default value in the URL and if not empty > use the url+value entered.

The current behavior works fine if something is entered, but if not, it simply goes to the URL (as the current script tells it to)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how? I'm open to any suggestions really

**EDIT** I have a special case where I need to keep the page's .html extension, so I can't use PHP.

Comment: If possible, I'd like the button.click function to do the validation. Click > check if empty > add NoName value or use entered value. Does that make sense at all? Sorry if I'm not explaining well. To put this into context, the form is on a page with a google map. Most of the user interaction is done on a map, but if an employee is using it and needs to go to their portal, they need to enter their ID and hit the button and their portal will open in a new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well is as simple as you described: `if empty > use default value in the URL and if not empty > use the url+value entered.`

just use simple if else, I made small [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juh29ajq/5/) for you.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you @Albert. I had something similar I was muddling with, but out of order. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

get the user value

```
var userValue=$('#rep').val();
```

then check if user value is null or empty

```
if(userValue){ }
```

if it is empty then use default value

```
$(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
 var myDefault="http://url.com";
var userValue=$('#rep').val();
if(userValue){   location.href=userValue; }
else {  //use  default
location.href=myDefault; }
});
 });
```

Comment: try to add some description to your answer

Comment: Somebody incorrectly flagged your answer as low-quality. You should add some accompanying text to explain how your answer works to prevent further flagging and/or downvotes. A code-only answer [is not low-quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358757/1364007). Does it attempt to answer the question? If not, flag as 'not an answer' or recommend deletion (if in the review queue). b) Is it technically incorrect? Downvote or comment. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18812850).